# Vala get file modification date

Tags: vala

I'm new to Vala and linux programming in general.

Im am trying to enumerate the data similar to the 'stat' shell utility for a given folder.
So far it's this i got:

```
int main (string[] args) {
    try {
        File directory = File.new_for_path (".");

        if (args.length > 1) {
            directory = File.new_for_commandline_arg (args[1]);
        }

        FileEnumerator enumerator = directory.enumerate_children (FileAttribute.TIME_MODIFIED, 0);

        FileInfo file_info;


        while ((file_info = enumerator.next_file ()) != null) {

          DateTime t = file_info.get_modification_date_time();

        }

    } catch (Error e) {
        stderr.printf ("Error: %s\n", e.message);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Console output:

```
vala --pkg gio-2.0 --pkg glib-2.0 main3.vala 
main3.vala:16.24-16.59: error: The name `get_modification_date_time' does not exist in the context of `GLib.FileInfo?'
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Comment: Note the `?` in `GLib.FileInfo?`, that means the value might be `null`. If it is `null` the `get_modification_date_time` doesn't exist because it's well `null`, you need to prove the value isn't null with something like `if (info != null)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is saying the method doesn't exist. Looking at Valadoc.org for [`get_modification_date_time`](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.FileInfo.get_modification_date_time.html) it shows this was introduced in GLib version 2.62. That [version was released](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/tags/2.62.0) 05 September 2019. It is likely your distribution doesn't include that release yet.

You can either try to update your version of GLib or use the now deprecated `get_modification_time`:

```
int main(string[] args) {
    if (args[1] == null) {
        stderr.printf("No filename given\n");
        return 1;
    }
    var file = GLib.File.new_for_path (args[1]);

    try {
        GLib.FileInfo info = file.query_info("*", FileQueryInfoFlags.NONE);
        print (info.get_modification_time().to_iso8601() + "\n");

        print ("\n\nFull info:\n");
        foreach (var item in info.list_attributes (null)) {
            print( @"$item - $(info.get_attribute_as_string (item))\n" );
        }
    } catch (Error error) {
        stderr.printf (@"$(error.message)\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```